# How to separate Interactors that must be in core layer and are triggered from Presenter

Tags: android, multithreading, mvp

I am implementing MVP pattern in Android. I have separate modules for Presenter, Interactors (Business-Logic) and data-access layer.

1. How do I separate Interactors that must be in core layer and are triggered from Presenter and have some kind of thread (must not have Android Framework dependency like Handler or AsyncTask… )?
2. How do I get result back to presenter layer when thread is finished interactor module?

Comment: use service and broadcast receiver if you dont want to use handler or asynctask

Comment: I want to make my interactor layer free of android framework. I want to accomplish this task using plain java.

Answer (score 2):

Actually i had wrong concept about the Handler. Handler is only way to communicate with the UI thread or Main thread by posting Runnable object from working thread. I used ThreadPoolExecutor to accomplish multithreading and used handler to communicate between threads in the threadpool and UI Thread. Anybody intrested in this approach can see the implementation in this this [link](https://github.com/sam33rdhakal/MVPandroid).

Comment: Hey, what about using EventBus? Now I'm going to try posting events on interactor completion instead of callbacks.

Comment: EventBus is a nice idea. I use Rxjava to emit the data.

Answer (score 0):

One way may be using https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid so you can subscribe to any thread and get responses on main thread easily.